# How do I do a multiple level Nested Loop Join?

Tags: python, sql-server-2012, hierarchical-data

I'm sure this must be a common coding question, but I don't even know what to call it.

For any given Person, I want to find their team - now there may be teams inside of teams, or maybe there are not - it's not predictable.

So I can just do nested loops which is fine, but I'm wondering if there is smarter fancier way of doing it? I'll just end up iterating over the same dataset (about 10,000 records, representing maybe 7 levels of hierarchy) over and over again, which isn't the most efficient.

MS SQL Server 2012? Python 3.10?

| PersonID | PersonName | Lev3 | Lev2 | Lev1 | ManagerID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4703 | John | Department A | Group D | Division A | 5763 |
| 4367 | Janet | Department B | Group E | Division B | 4744 |
| 7033 | Bob | Department C | Group D | Division A | 5763 |
| 5763 | Sarah | None | Group D | Division A | 5224 |
| 4744 | Phil | None | Group E | Division B | 5224 |
| 5224 | Petra | None | None | None | None |

Let's say I want to find Petra's team - ID 5224 - it should be everybody, since she is top of the food chain. But Phil? ID 4744 - that's only Janet. Compared to Sarah - ID 5763 who has both John and Bob in her team.

This SQL code will identify only the immediate team - not the teams within teams.

```
SELECT
   M.[Employee Name], S.[Employee Name]
FROM [Staff] M
JOIN [Staff] S
ON M.PositionID = S.ManagerPosition
WHERE 
    M.PositionID > 0
ORDER BY 
    m.[Employee Name]
```

How could I so a nested loop with a nested loop, within a nested loop - upto 7 levels deep?

Comment: You will need to use a recursive CTE.  Read this and see if you can apply it to your case: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Comment: Make it an answer and I can close this question as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a recursive CTE. Read this and see if you can apply it to your case:  https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Comment: That is great. .. Results are produced in under 2 seconds